# Drag&Drop in jQuery on Table Cells

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, cell

I have a table and need to drag/drop cells containing data into blank cells. I'm able to drag and drop fine, but once a cell is dragged away, I need its "old" position to now become a droppable cell. Since the cell is dragged, I need something else to reference. I ended up wrapping each of the td elements in a div element, but all references return "undefined" on the inner cellDiv id (or return the outer tableDiv id). On the fiddle, I notice that the blue background is not appearing so I don't think the 'cellDiv' is doing much.

Next I am going to try swapping the td and cellDiv elements, but I decided to post the question first, as I've searched everywhere and cannot seem to find this specific problem addressed. Thanks for your help.

here is the problem in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgsz34hx/3/
And the code:

```
<div id='tableDiv'>
    <table>
    <tr id='row1'>
        <div class='cellDiv' id='r1c1'>
            <td class='drop' id='col1'>Drop Here</td></div>
        <div class='cellDiv' id='r1c2'>
            <td class='nodrop' id='col2'>Drag Me</td></div>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var fromDiv;
    $('.nodrop').draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        appendTo: "body",
        revert: "invalid",

        start: function (event, ui) {
            var thisDiv = $(this).attr('id');
            fromDiv = $(this).closest('.cellDiv').attr('id');
            alert("thisDiv=" + thisDiv + ", fromDiv=" + fromDiv);
        } 
    });

    $('.drop').droppable({
        accept: ".nodrop",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        snap: ".drop",

        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var parenttd = $(ui.draggable).closest('td').attr('id');
            var parentdiv = $(ui.draggable).closest('.cellDiv').attr('id');
```

//                alert("parenttd=" + parenttd + ", parentdiv=" + parentdiv);

```
            $(this).removeClass('drop');
            $(this).addClass('nodrop');
            $(this).droppable('option', 'disabled', true);
        }
    });
});


#tableDiv {
    background-color: grey;
}
#tableDiv td {
    background-color: red;
}
#tableDiv div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tgsz34hx/12/ : here I moved the div inside the td so the div is draggable. I am now able to reference both the div and the td in the drop function; however I still cannot drop there once the div is dragged away.

Comment: I guess nobody else has had this problem. It took me a while, but I think I got it working. The key was line 20. Check out the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgsz34hx/54/